# SSIS package having problem with datename(dw,datum) converting to varchar

Tags: sql-server, unicode, ssis, non-unicode

I am moving data into a DW using SQL Server SSIS and have the following SQL to populate one dimension

```
SELECT DISTINCT
cast (datename(dw,datum) as varchar(10)) as veckodag 
FROM XXXXX.dbo.Bought
```

as I have VARCHAR in the target column I need to CAST/CONVERT

**Question** how to convert Unicode to Varchar?

I get

*> Validation error. Datum OLE DB Source

> [1]: Column "veckodag" cannot convert
>   between unicode and non-unicode string
>   data types.   Package.dtsx    0   0*

Comment: if you try "cast (datename(dw,datum) as nvarchar(10)) as veckodag" what happens?

Comment: Thanks Dan that was the rub

I changed the cast to nvarchar and then added a Data Transformation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SSIS use "Data Conversion Transformation" inside data flow

Comment: I have tested that but I get still an error.. I will do a new test

Comment: Cast it as nvarchar(10) and then go through the transformation.